# Отправка файлов средствами PHP

Tags: php, html, email, html-form

Вот HTML

```
  <form>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Invest offer">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="customAttach">Attach business plan</label>
            <input type="file" id="customAttach">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Как сделать отправку файлов на почту с помощью PHP?
Желательно чтобы было через ajax

Comment: в какм месте у вас проблемы?

Comment: не знаю как на php это реализовать

Comment: поищите в гугле, тут, как правило, помогают код починить, но он должен быть

Comment: собственно, тут две задачи - отправить файл через ajax - это делается криво. Если перезагрузка страницы не очень страшна, проще отправить через post. И вторая - отправка почты - реализация которой зависит от очень многих факторов